# iOSアプリ開発。画面に数式をテキストで表示させる方法はありますか？

Tags: ios, xcode

iPhoneアプリを開発しています。ある画面で、数式を表示させたいのですが、imgとして表示ではなくテキストとして表示させたいのですが、何かよい方法はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

テキストで数式をそのまま貼り付けることは、基本的にはできません。
Wordなどには数式を扱える機能がありますが、あれはワードプロセッサに付属している機能であり、テキストそのものではありません。
LaTeXなどの組版ソフトでは、数式の情報を含んだテキスト(例えば \frac{A}{B})をテキスト形式で保存し、それをレンダリングすることで数式を表示しています。
このため、質問の意図として「数式をテキストとして保存して」「iOS上に数式として表示する」とすると、自力での実装は難しいと思います。
あらかじめ表示する数式が決まっているのなら、それを画像形式にするのが最も手っ取り早いでしょう。
もっと複雑な数式を扱いたいなら(例えば関数電卓を作るなど)、Webブラウザ+JavascriptでLaTeX形式の数式をレンダリングしてくれるMathJax
https://www.mathjax.org/
があるため、それを使うのが良いと思います。おそらくWebViewでも使えます。

Answer (score 1):

あなたが望むようなものはありません。UILabelやUITextViewには数式を表示する機能は組み込まれていません。NSAttributedStringを使って画像を表示するか。WebViewで表示するかどちらかを使うのが良いと思います

Comment: 通信を使わない前提だと、画像で組み込むしかなさそうですね。
ありがとうございます。